# GEE can't find SR Sentinel-2 image of a specific date, but I can download it on Copernicus Browser

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

When I try to access a specific Sentinel-2 image on GEE, it doesn't show any results, even though I can find and download it in the Copernicus Browser. This is the code I have tried:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2017-08-14', '2017-08-16')
                  .filterBounds(study_area)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',50))
                  .map(maskS2clouds);
```

If I only look for `'COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED'`, my image shows up.

What does that mean?

I can download it on Copernicus Browser (this image:
`S2B_MSIL2A_20170815T093029_N0208_R136_T34UFU_20221104T120411`). As far as I understand, the `MSIL2A` means that it is atmospherically corrected Surface Reflectance images.

Why can't I access it through GEE?

Comment: Could you share your study area? Alternatively, you can tell us what Sentinel-2 tile you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this is because Earth Engine does not access level 2B images, only level 2A.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).